# What would happen if Java class has no constructor?

Tags: java

I was confused by constructor for many days , reading many code and books ,but still did not fully understand what constructor actually is.
Could any one show what would happen without constructor in Java?

Comment: you wouldn't be able to create objects/instances of classes, basically: you would only be able to use primitive datatypes.

Comment: Even you don't write any constructor, a default constructor exists there. So you can still create objects without passing any parameters. But if you want to create an object by passing parameters, you must define a constructor.

Comment: By the way, all classes inherit from the `Object` class, so if you don't write a constructor on your class, you still have the one from the `Object` class. So ALL classes have a constructor.

Comment: @NabinBhandari the question is not: "what if I don't put a constructor", it is "what if there weren't constructors in Java". Explaining the default constructor is nice, but not really relevant here.

Comment: @Stultuske chill out man, that was just a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @NabinBhandari true, but still, the comment is not about what is asked. No harm in mentioning that, is there?

Comment: Please understand that SO is not a replacement for you doing that *learning* part. There are zillions of books out there explaining what constructors are, how to use them, what happens if you dont provide one in your class.

Comment: If constructors weren’t a thing, there would be another way to instantiate a class.

Answer (score 4):

All classes have a constructor. If you don't specify one, you will get a default constructor with no parameters.

So when you do this:

```
class Test {

}
```

You will actually get this:

```
class Test {
  Test() {
    super(); // This is a call to the constructor of the Object class.
  }
}
```

The constructor lets you create instances of the class with the `new` keyword. Like this:

```
Test test = new Test(); // This calls the default constructor.
```

If there weren't constructors in Java, you wouldn't be able to create objects.